# REST API post field validation Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I need to check if I have all posted variables are required or else throw error.
Till Now I am doing like this

Routes.php

```
Route::post('/api/ws_fetchuser', 'UserController@fetch_user_details');
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
  public function fetch_user_details(Request $request)
    { 
        if(!empty($request) && $request->id!='')
        {
            print_r($request->id);    
        }
        else
        {
            return response(array(
            'error' => false,
            'message' =>'please enter all form fields',
            ),200);        
        }

    }
}
```

I am checking like this `$request->id!=''`, is there any validation rules or methods which I can use to check id is required field.

I have added this validation in my controller as well but what if id is not present how can I show the error?

Updated Validation Code:

```
public function fetch_user_details(Request $request)
    { 
        $this->validate($request, [
        'id' => 'required'
        ]);

        print_r($request->id);

    }
```

Comment: Have you [RTM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation)?

Comment: I have , but I am doing rest api so how come i show $errors ?

Comment: see @fubar I have updated my code and added validation my issue is what if id is not posted then how can I handle them?

Comment: If you're making a JSON request, Laravel will return errors in JSON format. Or you can catch the exception and build your own response.

Comment: Can  You pls show me the example as if validatin errors are returned in View, and rest API does not have veiws so how can I handle and show them error reponse? Can you pls show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->validate()` methods designed to redirect back when validation failed, So instead of that you can create a validator instance and get the error list manually.

```php
use Validator;


$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'id'    => 'required'
    ]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return json_encode($validator->errors()->all());
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion